# Redirect domains to different ports on same machine

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, json

I used the following command to redirect `80` to `3000`. All the requests that come, from any domain, are redirected to `3000`:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Having to processes: one that listens on `80001` and another one that listens on `8002` how can I link two domains to the two ports?

Is it possible to have a JSON configuration like below?

```
[
    {
       "port": 8001,
       "domains": ["example.com", "example2.com"] 
    },
    {
       "port": 8002,
       "domains": ["domain.com", "domain2.com"] 
    }
]
```

So, `domain.com`, `domain2.com` will send their requests to the process that listens on `8002` and the other two domains on `8001`?

Comment: Have you considered using a Reverse Proxy?

Comment: @garethTheRed Well, I don't have any idea how I can solve this... The only thing that I have done is at process level to check out the `request.headers.host` (that is the domain name). But I need different processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you would have to setup your web server with [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) and maybe [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) (for Apache).

However, I would suggest that you use a reverse proxy such as [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) to take care of that. Setup Haproxy  so that it listens to port 80 and direct your traffic to your webservers using ACLs on the domain name. Setup your webserver with virtual hosts that listen to 127.0.0.1:8002 and 127.0.0.1:80001 (if haproxy runs on the same server).

Pretty simple setup.

Look at [this example](http://oskarhane.com/haproxy-as-a-static-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers/). It's for putting haproxy in front of Docker containers, but you can adapt the configuration to suit your needs.

Comment: And how to use it? Can you add an example?

Comment: @IonicăBizău I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `apache`:

This might be a simple starting point - especially if you are considering hosting your two processes using `apache`.  Note that, as @Tony mentions, there are more efficient proxies available, which are definitely worth considering if you are not using `apache` to host your processes.

You need to find the `httpd.conf` file for your particular distro.  They do vary in name and location, so you'll have to read the docs or Google.  The example below is based on CentOS 7 (running `apache` v2.4)

In the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file, add:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8001
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost example2.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8001
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8002
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8002
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain2.com:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8002
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8002
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to restart (or reload) `apache` to make it read the new configuration.

Use your firewall to ensure that ports 8001 and 8002 aren't accessible from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

When you use DNAT, it's possible use the following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:8001

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:8002
```

You have to change 10.10.10.10 to your machine.

Comment: Where are the domain names used here? The only difference is `8001` vs `8002`.

Comment: When you use NAT, nat implements a session system according to your packet.(src addr and dst addr)